# proxy software to relay email

Tags: smtp, smtp-auth

My some software applications need to relay emails to my email account.

The only way they can do it via connecting to localhost which relays mail on behalf of application.

I have forgotten the name of such a software it is a Debian/Ubuntu environment.

Can any one let me know the name of such an proxy software which relays mail to your local SMTP server on behalf of application I will need to enter username password also in this setting because the mail server needs authentication.

Comment: What software needs mail relayed? Why can't it connect to the mail server directly?

Comment: "I have forgotten the name of such a software it is a Debian/Ubuntu environment" -- probably [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html); it's part of most Linux distros (at least the *useful* ones).

Comment: @blueben: Software that follows the [traditional Unix method](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MailConcept) of invoking `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and letting the MTA take care of transmission and delivery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok thanks all I found `nullmailer` is the software I was looking for.

It is a ubuntu package which can deliver mail on behalf of a software to the corporate mail server with authentication as a user.As I can not run a MTA so nullmailer suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Standard servers include exim, postfix, and sendmail.  I would prefer exim or postfix over sendmail.  The command `aptitude search smtp` lists a number of relay only tools.

Try the command `aptitude show mail-transport-agent` for a complete list of packaged mail transport agents.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). This will relay messages on your behalf.

> (MTA) or mail relay is software that
>   transfers electronic mail messages
>   from one computer to another using a
>   client–server application
>   architecture. An MTA implements both
>   the client (sending) and server
>   (receiving) portions of the Simple
>   Mail Transfer Protocol.

It's essential the same as running your own mail server, however in the case you describe you don't accept incoming mail, just relay outgoing mail.

Example of MTA are: sendmail, postfix, qmail, etc.